# Application gateway URL path-based routing always redirect to default backend pool

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have configured 4 webapps behind Application gateway (ARM template):

- dummyapi1.azurewebsites.de/servicehosts/dummyapi1
- dummyapi2.azurewebsites.de/servicehosts/dummyapi2
- dummyapi3.azurewebsites.de/servicehosts/dummyapi3
- dummyapi4.azurewebsites.de/servicehosts/dummyapi4

[web app settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r457V.png)

I can open web apps when I go directly to  dummyapiX.azurewebsites.de/servicehosts/dummyapiX.

I want routing work this way: when I go to https://PIPofApplicationGateway/servicehosts/dummyapiX it should redirect to

dummyapiX.azurewebsites.de/servicehosts/dummyapiX

But Application Gateway always redirect to default backend pool, therefore I get 404 error.

I created Custom probes that point to:

- /servicehosts/dummyapi1
- /servicehosts/dummyapi2
- /servicehosts/dummyapi3
- /servicehosts/dummyapi4

Backend health show Healthy status for all. Backend pools point to webapps FQDN. PickHostNameFromBackendAddress for httpsSettings and PickHostNameFromBackendHttpSettings for probes are set to true. No other Path related setting are not configured in httpsSettings.

The only path-based rule is:

- default backendpool  is dummyapi4
- "/servicehosts/dummyapi1/*" to backendpooldummy1
- "/servicehosts/dummyapi2/*" to backendpooldummy2
- "/servicehosts/dummyapi3/*" to backendpooldummy3

Any suggestion? What might be a root cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause was trailing "/" in path in rules.

So instead of:

```
"/servicehosts/dummyapi1/*" to backendpooldummy1
"/servicehosts/dummyapi2/*" to backendpooldummy2
"/servicehosts/dummyapi3/*" to backendpooldummy3
```

It should be in my case

```
"/servicehosts/dummyapi1*" to backendpooldummy1
"/servicehosts/dummyapi2*" to backendpooldummy2
"/servicehosts/dummyapi3*" to backendpooldummy3
```

Now everything works

Comment: you save my day/night  man !

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can confirm if you have created the virtual directory in your web app setting. Make sure the URL-based rule maps to the specific backend pool. Create the basic listener with a listening request port. Create and map a Path-based rule and bind to the listener. Get more details from this [tutorial](http://devchat.live/en/2018/07/02/how-to-map-url-path-based-rules-in-application-gateway-for-your-azure-web-app-service/).

Then, you can type `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear the DNS cache In the command prompt console. Verify it again.

Ref: [Error 404 : Web App Not Found – Azure Web App](http://www.ayushrathi.com/error-404-web-app-not-found-azure-web-app/)

Comment: First, I can confirm that my webapp are created as indicated in tutorial. Second, clear DNS cache does not help

Comment: I've updated topic with screenshot of Web App settings

Comment: Can you show the Path-based rule and how to bind to the listener?

Comment: I have only one HTTPS listener and one path-based rule that  binded to this listener, It is 3 rules "/servicehosts/dummyapiX/*" to "backendpooldummyX"

Comment: tbh, this thing from [tutorial](http://devchat.live/en/2018/07/02/how-to-map-url-path-based-rules-in-application-gateway-for-your-azure-web-app-service/) bugs me: "Before we start to map this, we should know the route you mapped for your web apps should be the **application root path of your web app** " In my case WebApp VirtualDirectory settings are not as in tutorial, because WebApps are in subfolder /servicehosts/. Even if WebApps are accessible by  URLs, it might not work with path-based routing

Comment: So the root cause is the wrong virtual directory settings for your web apps in this case.